# How to access "locked" files for backup program

Tags: python, windows, locking, backup

I am trying to create a google drive like backup program using python that backs up to a Linux box that will further backup to an off site place tbd. I have ran into a few interesting coding and computer challenges in doing this.

The one I am working on right now has to do with "locked" files. So what do I mean by this? In windows 7 if you create a .txt file you can open it in notepad(any program) and at the same time you can open it in a python program. If you make a change in the .txt file and save the change but BEFORE closing it you can still open and see the changes in pythn. Now change the file to a .docx windows file and open it with word 2007. While opened in word you cannot access it with in python until the user closes it.

Now if you look at google drive, the desktop install not the web only variety, you can open a .docx file and change it. Once you save it but BEFORE closing google drive has already synched the file.

Google drive must have some sort of lower level access to the file than the simple python file.open() command.

So here is the question. Does anyone know of a way to access files in python in such a way as to keep me from having to wait for the user to close the file.

Edit 1:
Let me further explain. Once I have created an sqlite database that has all the files and directories I will then use the win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW() function to monitor for changes. My problem stems from the fact that when setting up the application of first install/run it must catalog all files and files that are open in windows office are locked and cannot be cataloged. Is there a way around this?

Comment: But what have you tried so far? Have you looked into the win32api? Have you searched anything like [this](http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2011/10/how-to-acquire-locked-files-from.html) or other things?

Comment: did you try to open word files over network or local? It is a big difference.

Comment: Files were opened locally as they would be during normal operation of the backup program.

Answer (score 0):

Many backup tools use snapshots. Then, they'll copy the locked file directly from the snapshot rather than coping it directly from the filesystem. If you're on Windows you should check [Windows VSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy), see the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968832(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details. Otherwise, if the filesystem you're on supports snapshots check its documentation as well.

## Third party tools

You can use the `subprocess` Python module to run third-party tools which will take snapshots for you.

## Microsoft VSS

In case you want to do it by yourself you might need modules from the Win32 API such as `win32com` module.

There is also on Github a project that seems to do the job: pyshadowcopy

## Filesystem Snapshot

Depending on the filesystem features, you might find python modules or tools allowing you to take a snapshot.